# can not insert MCRYPT encrypted data to the database

Tags: php, mysql, encryption, pdo, mcrypt

I'm using MCRYPT to encrypt sensitive data and save them to the database. The encrypted data look like this (non-encrypted data above the encrypted data)

[image: real data above the encrypted data]

then insert to the MySQL PDO database as usual in a text field utf8_unicode_ci but the result is empty most of the times. Sometimes it saves only the first character. So how to save the encrypted value into the database?

```
$stmt=$db->prepare("insert into TABLE (myData) VALUES (:enc) ");
$stmt->bindParam(':enc',$encrypted);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: Provide the table creation statement, just to make it really clear. You try to post the encrypted value into a TEXT field? (Why not use a Byte field?)

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP using mcrypt and store the encrypted in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26756322/php-using-mcrypt-and-store-the-encrypted-in-mysql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

additionally encode base64

encode after encryption

```
base64_encode($encrypted)
```

and decode before decryption

```
base64_decode($encrypted)
```

Answer (score 0):

do you get an exception from pdo??

with this little information i would guess you want to save the data into a varchar field.

You may need to change your varchar field to a varbinary field.